# Formal Arguments Evaluation and Lexical Scoping in R

Tags: r, function, arguments, lexical-scope

I have been reading Hadley Wickham's Advanced R in order to gain a better understanding of the mechanism or R and how it works behind the scene. I have so far enjoyed and everything is quite clear, there is one question that occupy s my mind for which I have not yet found an explanation.
I am quite familiar with the scoping rules of R which determines how values are assigned to FREE VARIABLES, However I have been grappling with the idea that why R cannot find the value of a formal argument through lexical scoping in the first case? consider the following example:

```
y <- 4
f1 <- function(x = 2, y) {
  x*2 + y
}

f1(x = 3)
```

I normally throws and error cause I didn't assign a default value for argument `y`, however if I create a local variable `y` in the body of the function it won't throw any error:

```
f1 <- function(x = 2, y) {
  y <- 4
  x*2 + y
}

f1(x = 3)
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You have not passed y as an argument. So why would you want that not to be an error? The only arguments that dont need parameters are the default arguments. y is not a default argument and thus must have a parameter

Comment: I totally understand but what am I looking for here is why the value cannot be looked up through lexical scoping and use the value defined in the global environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified an argument `y` for the function, but not providing any value when asked for a value in return.  So this will work

```
f1(x = 3, y)
[1] 10
```

Here it takes `y` your defined variable as an input for the second argument which incidentally is also named y and returns a value.

even this will also work.  As you have defined a default value to this function

```r
y1 <- 4
f1 <- function(x = 2, y= y1) {
  x*2 + y
}
f1(x=3)
#> [1] 10
f1(x = 3, 5)
#> [1] 11
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

If you want to evaluate any function without giving any value for any argument, you have to define that in function itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This question was posted more than a month ago and I studied the topic ever since in depth. `f1(x = 3, y)` works because you assign `y` which is defined in the global environment to you so the function uses value `4` for argument `y`. So for this function to not throw an error we should either define a local variable named `y` within a funciton or consider a default value if we are not going to assign a value to `y` like you did at the beginning of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `y` in `f1()`, you just haven't bound a value to it.  The `y` that is in the global environment is a completely different variable.