# Function Argument Evaluation in R

Tags: r, function, default-arguments

I have been reading Hadley Wickham's Advanced R in the past couple of weeks and one particular concept has caught my attention which I would be grateful if you could provide me with an explanation:

> The evaluation environment is slightly different for default and user
> supplied arguments, as default arguments are evaluated inside the
> function.

and the following example is presented by the book:

```
h05 <- function(x = ls()) {
a <- 1
x
}
# ls() evaluated inside h05:
h05()
#> [1] "a" "x"
# ls() evaluated in global environment:
h05(ls())
#> [1] "h05"
```

Here it is quite clear that the when the user provide `ls()` as a value to argument x it is evaluated in the global environment. However in the following example when we provide 2 values for `x` and `y` it does not affect their value in the global environment, despite the fact they are being evaluated there:

```
y <- 6
x <- 5

f1 <- function(x, y) {
  x*2 + y
}

f1(x = 4, y = 12)
```

I would like to know what am I missing here and whether the aforementioned rule only holds true when we define and argument in terms of other arguments within a function call.

Any explanation in much appreciated.

Comment: This has the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/q/66623900/2554330 :  `x` and `y` in the function are different variables from `x` and `y` in the global environment.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I understand they are different because they reside in 2 different environments, however since the book says user-defined values are evaluated in the caller environment of the function which here is global environment I became baffled why it will not overwrite those 2 variables.

Comment: In `f1(x = 4, y = 12)`, the values the book is talking about are 4 and 12.  `x` and `y` are function argument names.

Comment: If you used something weird like `f1(x = (x <- 4), y = 12)`, the two `x` tokens would represent different variables:  the first is the argument name which becomes a local variable, the second is part of the expression evaluated in the global environment, so that **would** change the global value.

Comment: I understand now so that's why in the following code `f1(x = 4, y = y <- x)` the part being evaluated in `y<-x` so `y` takes the value of `x` in the global environment and at the same time the value of `y` is changed in there.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: By `local variable` you are referring to the variable defined in the body of the function?

Comment: Yes, sort of.  More precisely it is the variable defined in the function header.  It is the one that is visible in the function body.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful comments. It helped me a lot to understand what I was missing. You know I normally persist to fully grasp these kinds of issues sometimes when it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the discussion in comments, here is an answer:

The lines

```
y <- 6
x <- 5
```

create two global variables.

The function definition

```
f1 <- function(x, y) {
  x*2 + y
}
```

creates a function named `f1` that has two arguments named `x` and `y`.  When you call it, it will create variables `x` and `y` which are visible while evaluating the body of `f1`.  Those are called local variables.  They will normally disappear when the function is finished.  The values of those variables will be the values of the expressions being passed in.

When you call it as

```
f1(x = 4, y = 12)
```

it evaluates the expressions `4` and `12` in the global environment to find the values for the local variables.  The global variables `x` and `y` play no part in this.

If you do a call like

```
f1(x = 4, y = y <- x)
```

it will evaluate `4` as before, but when it evaluates `y <- x` it will be using the global variables:  so that changes the global value `y` to `5`.  It also sets the local variable `y` to `5`, because assignments return the value being assigned.

**Edited to add**:  the discussion above ignores "lazy evaluation", so things don't happen in the order described.  In fact, the arguments won't be evaluated until the local variables are used in the expression `x*2 + y`.  This makes no difference in this function, but in more complicated situations order of evaluation sometimes makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you very much again for taking time out to answer my question. I really appreciate it and I'm glad to finally find out the subtle difference here.